# book recommendation on Euclidean geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation

### this was my first question here and I asked it before I knew anything about this site like the dup questions

---

I want resources (books) for studying Euclidean geometry beyond the high school level. I have been searching for good books on this topic but haven't found any. Could you please provide me with recommendations or suggest good books for this subject to study it in more depth than high school geometry?

Comment: Note that under "Related" on this page there are links to many similar questions that have been asked & answered here before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prenowitz and Jordan, Basic Concepts in Geometry. Out of print, not easy to find, but worth looking for. Maybe a library can get it for you on interlibrary loan.

Comment: Used copies seem to be available [here](https://www.amazon.com/Basic-Concepts-Geometry-Walter-Prenowitz/dp/0471004510).

Comment: Don't respond to dupe. Take your time to find possible duplicate ( if any) or simply post your  thought as a comment.

Comment: @user, didn't occur to me that it might be a duplicate until after I posted my answer. I had seen requests for textbook recommendations before, but didn't remember seeing any for Geometry.